# Sparse matrix inverse multiplied by sparse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have the equation $\bf E = Y  D^{-1} Y^\top$.

$\bf D$ is a potentially large sparse $m \times m$ matrix, and $\bf Y$ is a sparse $n \times m$ matrix, where $n \ll m$.

Is there a particularly efficient known method for calculating the answer $\bf E$?

Comment: The inverse of a sparse matrix is not sparse in general. So it seems hard to exploit the potential sparseness of $D$.

Comment: But is there no way to exploit the fact that it is being pre and post multiplied by the sparse matrix Y, to produce a sparse E?